# Data table not working in laravel

Tags: php, laravel-5, datatables

I try following code but its give error.
My code:

```
 Dt = $('#mylist').dataTable({
            "dom": "<'row no-gutters'<'col-md-4'l><'col-md-4'r><'col-md-4'f>>t<'row no-gutters'<'col-md-4'i><'col-md-4'><'col-md-4'p>>",
            "processing": true,
            "ajax": "{{ URL::to('product/list') }}",
            "columnDefs": [
                {"orderable": false, "targets": [3, 4]},
            ],
            "order": [[0, "asc"]]
        });
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Can you show us the error message you got? The more details you give, the better we can help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Try this:**

You missed serverside : true in your code.

```
 oTable = $('#mylist').dataTable({
            "dom": "<'row no-gutters'<'col-md-4'l><'col-md-4'r><'col-md-4'f>>t<'row no-gutters'<'col-md-4'i><'col-md-4'><'col-md-4'p>>",
            "processing": true,
            "serverSide": true,
            "ajax": "{{ URL('product/list') }}",
            "columnDefs": [
                {"orderable": false, "targets": [3, 4]},
            ],
            "order": [[0, "asc"]]
        });
```